# how to populate the multiple textbox on one button click in php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i am working on radio button i need to populate the value of six text boxes on one button click i show mu problem in js fiddle here is the link :http://jsfiddle.net/sKrhY/ kindly help me in this .one thing i like to mention that on checking the radio button `a` `b` `c` a textbox appear in which user can enter the value on clicking the `calculate` button this value should also be display .plz help me in this
here is my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggle(value)
{
if(value=='show')
 document.getElementById('mytext').style.visibility='visible';
else
 document.getElementById('mytext').style.visibility='hidden';
}
</script>
<script>
function doCalc(){
    var input_value = parseInt( document.getElementById("value_input").value );
    document.getElementById("value_output").value = 100 * input_value;
      document.getElementById("value_output1").value = 100 * input_value;
        document.getElementById("value_output2").value = 100 * input_value; 
         document.getElementById("value_output3").value = 100 * input_value;
          document.getElementById("value_output4").value = 100 * input_value;
            document.getElementById("value_output5").value = 100 * input_value;
              document.getElementById("value_output6").value = 100 * input_value;
    return false;
};

document.getElementById("calc_button").onclick = doCalc;
</script>

<form method="POST" name="form1">
 No of Units (kwh) Used :<input type="text" id="value_input" value="123"></input><br/>
 select your categaory
<input type="radio"  name="myradio" checked="checked" onclick="toggle('hide');" />domestic
<input type="radio" name="myradio" checked="checked" onclick="toggle('show');">a
<input type="radio"  name="myradio" checked="checked" onclick="toggle('show');">b
<input type="radio" name="myradio" checked="checked" onclick="toggle('show');">c
 connected loads(kwh)
<input type="text" name="mytext" id="mytext">
  Actual <input type="text" id="value_output"></input><br/>
  tax <input type="text" name="text2"  id="value_output1" />
Elec <input type="text" name="text3"  id="value_output2" />
Charges <input type="text" name="text4"  id="value_output3" />
Amount <input type="text" name="text5"  id="value_output4" />
Govt <input type="text" name="text6"  id="value_output5" />
result <input type="text" name="text7"  id="value_output6" />
    <input id="calc_button" type="submit" name="Calculate" value="Calculate"></input>
</form>
```

Comment: populate where ?? on clicking calculate it is working

Comment: elaborate more. I can't understand your problem

Comment: populate textbox with values like if user enter 3 in number of units used then on clicking calculate button all six textbox that are actual to result are fill with 300

Comment: @Krishnanunni help me in this

Comment: @MoeedFarooqui help me  in this

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment you need to multiply the input number with `100`
For this:

```
document.getElementById("value_output").value = 100 + input_value;
```

Replace with this in all values of `value_output` like value_outpu1,2,3,so on:

```
document.getElementById("value_output").value = 100 * input_value;
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sKrhY/1)

According to your updated Question:
You are not calling the `docalc()` function.Try this:

```
<form method="POST" name="form1" onsubmit="return doCalc();">
```

Comment: sir when i copy this code on my page its not working but on fiddle its working what i do :(

Comment: Not working?? can you provide link if its live or try to find the error in console.

Comment: how can i show that if user select domestic in radio button then input multiply with 100 but if user select a in radio button then input multiply with 200 plz help in this

Comment: @ashy1234 I have posted another answer for your another question.:)

Answer (score 0):

For your Another Wishlist:
set the values in `radio` buttons

```
 <input type="radio" value="100"  name="myradio" checked="checked" onclick="toggle('hide');" />domestic
 <input type="radio" value="200" name="myradio" checked="checked" onclick="toggle('show');">a
```

Now you can get the values by `document.getElementByID('radio button id here')...` and Your formula will be:

```
var radio_button_value = document.getElementById('').value;
document.getElementById("value_output").value = radio_button_value * input_value;
```

Comment: where i put this code i dont understand the placement of this java scripting

Comment: Like you have done all the java script same thing can be happen with this too read my answer adn tell me the problem you are facing